# How to "remove" file from parent theme

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

I am having an issue with a theme I am using.

The parent theme has created a woocommerce.php file. When this file exists, it takes precedence over the woocommerce hooks, and it causes issues when I want to use hooks to add content before the woocommerce content.

Is it possible for a child theme to declare that the woocommerce.php file from parent should be ignored ?

Comment: What happens if you put a `woocommerce.php` file in the child theme?

Comment: It will override the parent one, but it means that if any update comes to the parent theme, I won't get it, or I will have to update this file (I guess it's not that bad, and updates are not likely to be that often).

Comment: Then could you not include it in your child themes file, then unhook the stuff you don't want?

Comment: This is the issue, the child theme contains only 2-3 files. If I don't include it in the child, the parent one will be taken. If I create a new one in the child, it will be used by woocommerce, and it is the one that will be used for layout, which means I still won't have the required hooks and default woocommerce behavior.

Comment: Just include it: `require( get_template_dir().'/woocommerce.php' );` then `remove_action` and `remove_filter` your way to success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child theme could just delete the parent theme file if it exists (via child theme functions.php). eg.

```
$template = get_template_directory().'/woocommerce.php'; 
if (file_exists($template)) {unlink($template);}
```

That would continue to override it if it came to exist again (ie. after a parent theme update.) If you aren't going to update the parent theme just delete it's `woocommerce.php`

If it's a file other than the WooCommerce files and just another file in the parent theme, copy it into the child theme and remove it's content just leave the `<?php ?>` tags if the content of the file is not needed.

Comment: Note that this could break the parent theme

Comment: I think in this case, it won't break it, will give it a try (but I will keep a backup, just in case). Ok, this seems to work fine, I will have to add a few hooks, but it seems fine.