# How to neutralize a parent theme php template?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, child-theme, twitter-bootstrap

I use to work a basic theme with a child-theme.
The parent theme contains the woocommerce.php template, which I would like to disable in the child theme. I already used several codes in the child theme's functions.php, but none worked. Can anyone imagine how I can neutralize this template?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "neutralize"?

Comment: Not clear your requirement.

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant disable that parent theme php template in the child-theme, but without overwriting it with another template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that with 'neutralize' you mean de-register or remove, such that WC doesn't see (or recognize) the file and functions as it would have without the `woocommerce.php`-file being there.

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/292595/60517) proposes a code in which your child theme (by code) physically deletes the parent theme file. There's also a questions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/how-to-remove-a-parent-theme-page-template-from-a-child-theme) that seems related to your problem.

Comment: Hi Bram, thanks for the reply.
Exactly, I want to disable this parent theme template in the child theme.
I already tried this and other codes that I found here, but I did not succeed.
Any other sugestion?

Comment: Any errors on running the first code? I cannot really think of a way why hard-deleting it from the parent theme folder wouldn't work. Have you tried de- and re-activating the (child) theme after making these changes?